# Adding user input from Edit Text into List View

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to get a user input from Edit Text into List View, I had seen the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295664/how-to-add-user-input-of-edittext-to-the-list-in-android) similar question but I'm unable to figure it out

I tried this, received no errors from the IDE, but it does not work

```
public class ListtestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button bt;
EditText et;
TextView tv;
ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String input = et.getText().toString();
    String[] values = new String[] {"", input};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Tried the following also

```
public class ListtestActivity extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter;
ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button bt;
EditText et;
TextView tv;
ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, m_listItems);
    lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    final String input = et.getText().toString();

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            m_listItems.add(new String(input));
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank You

*Very new to Android/Java/SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Second code snippet, change row of `m_adapter`

```
  m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_listItems);
```

Then add in String in `m_listItems`

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        String input = et.getText().toString();
        if(null!=input&&input.length()>0){     

        m_listItems.add(input);

        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the String to the adapter instead to the listview:

```
m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_listItems);//you can delete your previous initialisation

bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String strAddMe = et.getText().toString();
        if(strAddMe != null)
            m_listItems.add(strAddMe);

        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
    }
});
```

As the listview knows about the adapter, the adapter has to know about the content wich it "adapts" to the listview. Once you know what that means you can use adapters without any problems ;)

Furthermore you should read the editText as late as you need its input.

Comment: I get it, I should get the value of EditText when I need it instead of getting it too early.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the value of the EditText when you create your Activity, and it's empty. Put the line where you declare "input" into your onClick listener.

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String input = et.getText().toString();

        m_listItems.add(new String(input));
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand, meaning I tried getting the value of EditText too early, and I should only do it when I need it ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Exactly, when the value of the EditText changes, it won't update the value of your String, so you need to manually go get it whenever you need it.